# Does \noindent do anything besides removing the standard indent?

Tags: indentation

I'm new to LaTeX and while getting used to it and trying out different commands with \blindtext I noticed that \noindent causes the text to need *more* space than with the standard indent. Searching for \noindent didn't result in more than the command itself tells me.

Why is that? Does \noindent do more than removing the indent? Or are there any mechanics I'm not yet aware of that could cause this?

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

%\noindent
\blindtext[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\noindent` starts a new paragraph (even if it's empty), so if you use `\noindent\par` that'll produce an empty line in the output (plus optional `\parskip`).

Comment: @Skillmon are you sure?:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle oh, you're right, it doesn't create an empty line. But I wonder why, since `\noindent` enters horizontal mode, and `\par` should only be ignored in vertical or internal vertical mode. Can you give me a pointer where this behaviour is documented?

Comment: @Skillmon tex.web _There are also a number of implicit parameters: The hlist to be broken
starts at |link(head)|, and it is nonempty._  nonempty being key here, `\noindent\par` makes an empty hlst and as far as  I can tell the code after that quote skips the "add \parfillsip and break in to lines " code.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ah, ok, thanks! I don't recall this from the TeXbook (and a quick glance at the TeXbook was no help :()

Comment: @Skillmon it might be in the texbook somewhere but I suspect not

Comment: @Skillmon Documentation of behavior of `\noindent\par`: In TeXbook, Chapter 14: How TeX Breaks Paragraphs into Lines, right after exercise 14.29, you find one of these double-dangerous-bend-paragraphs - it says: *"A paragraph of zero lines is formed if you say ‘\noindent\par’. If \everypar is null, such a paragraph contributes nothing except \parskip glue to the current vertical list."*

Comment: @UlrichDiez wow, thank you very much for "hunting" this down!

Answer (score 2):

You should never need `\noindent` but as it changes the indent it changes the line breaking for the entire paragraph.

[image]

The third paragraph shows there is nothing special about `\noindent` here, you get the same line breaks with a *longer* last line by keeping indentation but removing a word `Lorem` from the first line

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=1cm, bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

%\noindent
\blindtext[2]

\bigskip

\noindent
\blindtext[2]

\bigskip

\makeatletter
\def\gobbleword#1 {}
\let\blindtext@text@orig\blindtext@text
\def\blindtext@text{%
\ifnum1=\blind@countxx\expandafter\gobbleword\blindtext@text@orig
\else\blindtext@text@orig\fi}
\makeatother
\blindtext[2]

\end{document}
```

---

If you use `\noindent` on its own (or if `\blindtext` had been written to start a new paragraph) then an empty paragraph is generated which will be dropped, but cause a double `\parskip` space:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\parskip 10pt

1aaa

\noindent

2aaa


3aaa

\end{document}
```

Comment: It just doesn't really make sense to me that the \noindent text ends up taking up more space. If you look at the blindtext from your answer, lines 3 to 5 are identical but in line 6 the indented text fits one more word. It has to change another formatting setting for the paragraph right?
Also, I didn't quite understand yet why I shouldn't ever use or ever need \noindent. Sometimes you just don't want the text to be indented. Or do you mean there's a better way to do it?

Comment: @1tr3mm3l7 You can turn on `\tracingparagraphs=2`  and debug but I didn't. It s a least cost optimisation over the whole  paragraph and there are so many variables including penalties for hyphenation which is already changed on line 1, so even though the breaks on some lines came out the same the final breaks differ again. Certainly there is nothing in `\noindent` specfically, you could see same by removing a word (rather than an indent) make the paragraph longer.

Comment: @1tr3mm3l7  Ideally whatever reason you do not indent is a structural context (eg after a section heading) and latex can be set up not to indent in that context with no document markup

Comment: @1tr3mm3l7  Updated to show the example without `\noindent` but removing `Lorem`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell `\noindent` has effect only when TeX is in (internal) vertical mode:

If TeX is in (internal) vertical mode while encountering `\noindent`, then TeX switches to horizontal mode.
Horizontal mode is the typesetting-mode where TeX does break the text of a paragraph into lines  for you automatically.
Switching from vertical mode to horizontal mode in turn implies inserting vertical `\parskip`-glue and starting a new horizontal list and carrying out the things stored in `\everypar`.

`\noindent` is similar to `\leavevmode`.

The most important differences are:

With `\leavevmode` a horizontal box of width `\parindent` is placed at the begin of the new horizontal list. Thus with `\leavevmode` the first line of the paragraph which TeX will create by typesetting subsequent material in horizontal mode will be indented horizontally.
With `\noindent` no such box is placed at the begin of the new horizontal list, thus with `\noindent` the first line of the paragraph which TeX will create by typesetting subsequent material in horizontal mode will not be indented horizontally.

With `\leavevmode` the new horizontal list in any case contains the horizontal box of width `\parindent` and thus in any case is not empty.
So with `\leavevmode` in any case a horizontal list is typeset which consists at least of the horizontal box of width `\parindent` (which in turn does not contain visible material) so that in any case a line of width `\hsize` preceded by vertical interline-glue calculated from `\baselineskip` and the height and depth of the line of text holding the `\parindent`-box will be inserted.

With `\noindent` the new horizontal list can be empty. In this case it will not be typeset, thus you neither get vertical interline-glue nor get a line of width `\hsize`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\parskip=1cm  \parindent=2cm

aaa

\noindent bbb %<-TeX is in vertical mode when encountering \noindent, thus \noindent triggers 
              %  switching to horizontal mode without inserting horizontal \parindent-glue.

ccc \noindent ddd %<-TeX is in horizontal mode when encountering \noindent, thus \noindent has no effect.

eee       % The empty line after this comment yields an endlinechar of category 5(end of line)
          % while the reading-apparatus is in state N(new line) so that TeX inserts the token
          % \par which in turn causes TeX to switch to vertical mode.

\noindent % TeX is in vertical mode, thus \noindent triggers switching to horizontal mode
          % and hereby inserting vertical \parskip-glue but no horizontal box of width \parindent.
          % The empty line after this comment yields an endlinechar of category 5(end of line)
          % while the reading-apparatus is in state N(new line) so that TeX inserts the token
          % \par which in turn causes TeX to switch to vertical mode.

fff       % When encountering the first f TeX switches from vertical mode to horizontal mode, hereby
          % inserting vertical \parskip-glue and horizontal box of width \parindent. Thus between eee
          % and fff you get vertical \parskip-glue twice.

$3+4\noindent=7$ %<-TeX is in math mode when encountering \noindent, thus \noindent has no effect.

$$3+4\noindent=7$$ %<-TeX is in math mode when encountering \noindent, thus \noindent has no effect.

\noindent
\fbox{%
\vbox{%
  % Settting \hsize has no effect as with \noindent the newly to create horizontal
  % list is empty and thus no material is typeset in horizontal mode where \hsize would apply to:
  \hsize=\dimexpr.5\textwidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep\relax
  \hbox{AAA}\noindent\par\hbox{AAA}
}}%
\fbox{%
\vbox{%
  % Settting \hsize has effect as with \leavevmode the \parindent-box is typeset in
  % horizontal mode whereby \hsize does apply:
  \hsize=\dimexpr.5\textwidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep\relax
  \hbox{AAA}\leavevmode\par\hbox{AAA}
}}%

\end{document}
```

[image]